# push ebp: operand type mismatch for `push'

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86

I'm trying to compile the following using gcc -c main.s

```
.intel_syntax noprefix

.global main

main:
    push   ebp
    mov    ebp,esp
    sub    esp,0x10
    mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0xc],0x0
    mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+0xc]
    mov    eax,DWORD PTR [eax+0x4]
    mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x4],eax
    leave
    ret
```

And I get an error:

> main.s:6: Error: operand type mismatch for `push'

What's the reason this isn't working?

Comment: Try to write a C near-equivalent function in `foo.c` and compile it with `gcc -O -fverbose-asm -Wall -S foo.c` then look into the generated `foo.s`

Comment: BTW, the assembler syntax varies from one `gcc` to the next one. In particular, the target and host operating systems are *very* important. Look into the output of `gcc -v` alone

Comment: Are you on a 64-bit machine?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch the code looks completely different, no wonder it won't compile....

Comment: @melpomene yes but I was able to compile other programs alread

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: This is GAS intel-syntax.  To get asm like what the OP has, use `gcc -masm=intel -S`.   (I agree with your recommendation to use `-O1` at least to get less noisy code.  [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116), but the code in the question could be the output of `gcc -m32 -O0 -masm=intel`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/39/c5/325462-sdm-vol-1-2abcd-3abcd.pdf), *7.3.1.5 Stack Manipulation Instructions in 64-Bit Mode*:

> In 64-bit mode, the stack pointer size is 64 bits and cannot be overridden by an instruction prefix. In implicit stack references, address-size overrides are ignored. **Pushes and pops of 32-bit values on the stack are not possible in 64-bit mode.**

(Emphasis mine.)

`push ebp` tries to push a 32-bit register, which is not allowed in 64-bit mode.

---

This is 32-bit code (and would crash in 64-bit mode even if `push ebp` was encodeable), so you need to assemble it into a 32-bit executable.  With gcc or clang, use

```
gcc -m32 -no-pie -fno-pie  main.s  -o my_prog
```

(The no-pie options are not necessary, but you probably want them to get a simpler position-dependent executable for 32-bit code.)

Comment: ok that makes sense. Can I force it to compile in 32bits mode?

Comment: @S.L. I believe gcc has a `-m32` option.